# Bounded sequence question

Tags: calculus

$(a_n)$ is a sequence. If it is known that $(a_{n+1} - a_n)$ is bounded, say True or False for the following:

A) There is $M>0$ so every $n > M$ : $$|a_n| \le |a_1| + (n-1)M$$
So I tried to say that $|a_{n+1} - a_n| < M$ (because it's bounded) but it lead me to nowhere how can I reach to $(n-1)$ and $a_1$? I feel lost in here.

B)$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{n^2} = 0$$
I feel like this one is true because I couldn't find an example that says otherwise but its not really a mathematical way of doing things.

If someone can shed some light on this I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)**
$$|a_n-a_1|\le\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(a_{k+1}-a_k)\right|\le\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}|a_{k+1}-a_k|\le M(n-1)$$
where $M$ is the bound for $|a_{k+1}-a_k|$

**2)**
$$0\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_n|}{n^2}\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_1|+M(n-1)}{n^2}=0$$

Comment: oh thanks could you explain a bit what you did there? (in both) cause I didnt get it

Comment: In 1) is much like as the trick to compute telescopic series, and then apply triangle inequality. In 2), simply substitute.

Comment: I didnt learn about the telescopic series so Im trying google to understand it, does $|a_n| - |a_1| = |a_n - a_1|$? Im not sure it works with negatives. and about the second one how did you determine that $|a_n| \le |a_1| + M(n-1)$

Comment: $|a_n-a_1|\le M(n-1)$ means that the distance between $a_n$ and $a_1$ is lesser than or equal to $M(n-1)$. Then, the absolute value of $a_n$ cannot be greater than $|a_1|+M(n-1)$. Draw a sketch if you don't see that.