# telescopic series & sum of sequences - how to?

Tags: calculus

The entire web shows the same example basicly(or something extremely similar): $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{-2}{(n+1)(n+2)}= \frac{-2}{3}$$
Is there a way to find this final answer without doing the pretty long procedure?

In addition to it I want to apply the telescopic series principal on the following sequence: $$(a_{n+1} - a_n)$$
How would I do it? [$a_n$ is sequence and $a_{n+1} - a_n$ is bounded]

Comment: What is that pretty long procedure?Could you give us a link or write it down yourself.

Comment: @DSinghvi basicly opening it up with A and B and then solving the equations like they show in khan academy video https://www.khanacademy.org/math/integral-calculus/sequences_series_approx_calc/calculus-series/v/telescoping-series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sequence $a_n$ converges to $a$, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_{n+1}-a_n)\stackrel1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n(a_{k+1}-a_k)\stackrel2=\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_1)\stackrel3=a-a_1$$

Step $2$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(a_{k+1}-a_k)=(a_2-a_1)+(a_3-a_2)+\ldots+(a_{n+1}-a_n)$$
But you can cancel all the terms but $a_{n+1}$ and $a_1$, so the sum is $a_{n+1}-a_1$.

Comment: I have edited my answer to put those numbers over the equal signs. In which step(s) is the problem?

Comment: do you mean by sequence $a_n$ converges to $a$ that $a_n$ -> $a$? if so what is $a$? ok at step 1 i see you replaced n with k this is fine, what happened at step 2?

Comment: $a_n$ converges to $a$ means that the limit of $a_n$ is $a$. Step two is the point of telescopic sums. Answer editing for clearing.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: **Telescoping**

Notice that

$$\frac{-2}{(n+1)(n+2)}=-2\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)$$

See Partial fraction Decomposition on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) or [on Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html)

I hope you can take it from here

Formula for Partial sum:
$$a_{p}=\sum_{n=0}^p\frac{-2}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{-2(p+1)}{p+2}$$

Comment: oh ok i see thanks

Comment: yup Im basicly upvoting any one who answers :D but I still didnt get the second part about the $(a_{n+1} - a_n)$

Comment: Yea maybe asking ~2 questions in one wasnt the best idea but they are talking about almost the same thing and I didnt want to spam this site :) isnt upvote worth as much as accepting?

Comment: $a_n$ is a sequence, $a_{n+1} - a_n$ is bounded if it differs

Comment: thats all the info I got, $a_n$ is a sequence and $a_{n+1} - a_n$ is known to be bounded, im refering to this question basicly http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015128/bounded-sequence-question/1015138#1015128

Comment: I think its too late to edit it since people already posted about the second part too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18540/discussion-between-kfir124-and-integrator).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, so basically the only sure way of completing this series is by doing the partial decomposition of the original series. Then by finding the coefficients of the fractions you should be able to see a cancellation. The only step left is to find the nth terms and write out the terms the terms that don't cancel which will be your answer.

Answer (score 1):

By partial fractions,

$$\frac{-2}{(n+1)(n+2)} \equiv \frac{A}{n+1} + \frac{B}{n+2}$$
For some $A$ and $B$.
Thus,
$$-2 \equiv A(n+2)+B(n+1)$$
By letting $n=-1$ and $n=-2$ in turn, we can see that $A=-2$ and $B=2$. So the sum is now:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{n=k}{\left(\frac{2}{n+2} - \frac{2}{n+1}\right)}=2\sum_{n=2}^{n=k}{\left(-\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2}\right)}$$
Which is
$$2\left(\left(-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left(-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}\right)+\left(-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}\right)+...+\left(-\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{k+1})\right)+\left(-\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+2}\right)\right)$$
Which, by the method of differences, is equivalent to
$$2\left(-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{k+2}\right)$$
If we limit $k$ to $\infty$, $\frac{1}{k+2}$ becomes $0$, thus our sum is $$-\frac{2}{3}$$
More generally, by the same method, $$\sum_{n=x}^{n=y}{(a_{n+1}-a_{n}})=a_{y+1}-a_{x}$$
Hope this helped!

Comment: very nice, if $y = \infty$ then what is $a_{\infty + 1}$

Comment: $a_{\infty+1}=a_\infty$, since it would simply represent the limit of $a_n$ as $n$ approaches infinity. (Remember that $\infty+1=\infty$)

Answer (score 1):

A well-known generalization
of your sum is this:

Consider the product of
the $k$ consecutive integers
starting at $n$,
$
n(n+1)...(n+k-1)
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac1{n(n+1)...(n+k-1)}-\dfrac1{(n+1)...(n+k)}
&=\dfrac{(n+k)-n}{n(n+1)...(n+k)}\\
&=\dfrac{k}{n(n+1)...(n+k)}\\
\end{array}
$

or
$\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)...(n+k)}
=\dfrac1{k}\left(\dfrac1{n(n+1)...(n+k-1)}-\dfrac1{(n+1)...(n+k)}\right)
$.

Adding $1$ to $k$,
$\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)...(n+k-1)}
=\dfrac1{k-1}\left(\dfrac1{n(n+1)...(n+k)}-\dfrac1{(n+1)...(n+k+1)}\right)
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^m \dfrac1{n(n+1)...(n+k-1)}
&=\sum_{n=1}^m \dfrac1{k-1}\left(\dfrac1{n(n+1)...(n+k)}-\dfrac1{(n+1)...(n+k+1)}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{k-1}\sum_{n=1}^m \left(\dfrac1{n(n+1)...(n+k)}-\dfrac1{(n+1)...(n+k+1)}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{k-1}\left(\dfrac1{1\cdot 2 ...\cdot (k+1)}-\dfrac1{(m+1)...(m+k+1)}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{k-1}\left(\dfrac1{(k+1)!}-\dfrac1{(m+1)...(m+k+1)}\right)\\
\end{array}
$

Letting $m \to \infty$,
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{n(n+1)...(n+k-1)}
=\dfrac1{(k-1)(k+1)!}
$.